# Xcode Shortcut to Search Errors on Google/Stack Overflow

Tags: xcode, scripting, shortcut

I do this 20 times a day and it's infuriating every time:

1. Write some code.
2. Get some opaque, useless swift error message that runs off the end of the display and I can't expand for some reason.
3. Open error sidebar.
4. Right click the error.
5. Copy.
6. Try to paste the error into Google search.
7. The copied error looks like a URL to chrome so it tells me it cant
   find the URL: /Users/kirby/src/SomeApp/SomeApp/SomeCode.swift:16:10:
   Expected identifier in function declaration.
8. Open up Stickies or TextEdit.
9. Remove the file path junk from the copied error.
10. Copy again without the file path.
11. Paste into Google search.
12. Get enlightened.

What I'd like to do:

1. Write some code.
2. Get some opaque, useless swift error message that I can see all of. (I dunno, maybe wrap the line or something! It's 2015!)
3. Right click the error.
4. Choose "Search in Google".
5. Get Enlightened.

Is there some Applescript or xcode plugin that does something like this? Is there a setting I'm missing? If not, can I write some kind of simple script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a somewhat quicker option.

1. Write some code.
2. Get some opaque, useless swift error message that runs off the end of the display before it gets to the point.
3. Right click error icon in gutter -> Reveal in Issue navigator.
4. Right click the error in Issue navigator -> Show in log
5. Highlight the error text in the log Right click -> Search With Google.

Still a lot of gymnastics for something so common but it's better than before.

Comment: i agree. unbelievable there isnt a shortcut for this - right click on issue and search for example... seems a no-brainer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Verrrrry slightly quicker.

1. Write some code.
2. Get some opaque, useless swift error message that runs off the end of 
   the display before it gets to the point.
3. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> is a shortcut to open the issue navigator.
4. Right click the error in Issue navigator -> Show in log
5. Highlight the error text in the log Right click -> Search With Google.
6. Sleep for days.

We are moving very slowly in the right direction.

I'm not sure if this is quicker but you could use the keyboard for a little longer by copying and pasting the error message directly from the issue tracker into a note app, such as the Apple Notes app. Then you can right click and hit Search with Google from there. The only caveat is you get a bunch of directory mumbo jumbo before your error message when you paste it for some reason.